# loadrequest cannot find cache entry that I created with NSURLCache

Tags: ios, objective-c, caching, uiwebview

I can create a cache entry by:

```
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] storeCachedResponse:cachedURLresponse forRequest:request];
```

for the URL http://www.punkoffice.com/hello.html

If I run this straight after I see that my cache entry exists

```
NSLog(@"cache = %@",[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] cachedResponseForRequest:request]);
```

and i can see it in the SQLite database file.

However, when I do a loadrequest with the exact same request like so:

```
[self.webView loadRequest:request]
```

The cache entry for that request isn't found and a new one is created.  It ends up over-writing the cache entry I put in there previously.

How do I get loadRequest to see the cache entry I stored with storeCachedResponse?

(edit)
Here is the full code I'm using to create the cache entry.  I can tell this bit works 'cos it exists in the cache database and I can retrieve it from cachedReponseForRequest

```
NSString *strURL = @"http://www.punkoffice.com/hello.html";
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];
NSString *strData = @"<html><body>Some other content</body></html>";
NSData *dataContent = [strData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSURLResponse *response = [[NSURLResponse alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL] MIMEType:@"text/html" expectedContentLength:[dataContent length] textEncodingName:nil];
NSCachedURLResponse *cachedURLresponse = [[NSCachedURLResponse alloc] initWithResponse:response data:dataContent];
```

I have also tried adding headers like so:

```
NSDictionary *headers = @{@"Cache-Control":@"max-age=3600"};
NSHTTPURLResponse* httpResponse = [[NSHTTPURLResponse alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL] statusCode:200 HTTPVersion:@"HTTP/1.1" headerFields:headers];
NSCachedURLResponse *cachedURLresponse = [[NSCachedURLResponse alloc] initWithResponse:httpResponse data:dataContent];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. To resolve this, I have done it like this.

```
    NSCachedURLResponse *cachedResponse = [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] cachedResponseForRequest:request];
    if (cachedResponse) {
        [myWebView loadData:cachedResponse.data MIMEType:cachedResponse.response.MIMEType textEncodingName:cachedResponse.response.textEncodingName baseURL:request.URL];
    }
    else{
        [myWebView loadRequest:request];
    }
```

Not sure, but it seems to me that `loadRequest` method of `UIWebView` always ignores the `cachePolicy` and always tries connecting to the server at `request URL` instead looking into cache.

Comment: That works for loading web pages, thanx!  Now I'm trying to get it to work for resources within the web page.  I now have an image dancer.jpg inside the hello.html page.  So if I insert a cache entry for dancer.jpg and call hello.html via your method it can't find the cache entry, but if I go directly to www.punkoffice.com/dancer.jpg using your method it does find the cache entry.  I'm not sure how I can apply your workaround to resources within a web page.

Comment: I've seen people store their manually created cache entries in a dictionary.  I have a bad feeling this is the only way to store and retrieve cache entries.  I was really hoping to use the existing cache database instead of storing all new cache responses in memory.

Comment: I had the similar fight with the default cache and I felt the default cache is not much reliable. May be that is why many developers store the responses/resources in form of NSDictionary/NSData. I suugest you another option to save the whole response in the Core-data. See if that suits your requirement.

Comment: I am able to create my own caching storage and override the existing NSURLCache functions to use that storage.  That's my last resort. So I'm guessing its not possible to use the existing NSURLCache functions as is and the official cache database.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the **`cachePolicy`** when creating the **`NSURLRequest`**.

```
+ (id)requestWithURL:(NSURL *)theURL cachePolicy:(NSURLRequestCachePolicy)cachePolicy timeoutInterval:(NSTimeInterval)timeoutInterval
```

Value of the cachePolicy should be NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad.

> **NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad**
>
> Specifies that the existing cached
>   data should be used to satisfy the request, regardless of its age or
>   expiration date. If there is no existing data in the cache
>   corresponding the request, the data is loaded from the originating
>   source.

In order to take advantage of NSURLCache, a shared URL cache must be initialized and set.

```
  NSURLCache *URLCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:4 * 1024 * 1024 
                                                       diskCapacity:20 * 1024 * 1024 
                                                           diskPath:nil];
  [NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:URLCache];
```

You should also make sure the response contains the Cache-Control HTTP header. This header must be present in the response from the server to enable HTTP caching by a client.

Comment: That doesn't make a difference.  It is still overwriting it with the contents of the web page.  I'm using this:     
`NSString *strURL = @"http://www.punkoffice.com/hello.html";`
`NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad timeoutInterval:60.0];`
`[self.webView loadRequest:request];`

Comment: Are you initializing your NSURLCache? I updated my answer. Have a look.

Comment: yep.  I'm using those exact figures for memory and disk capacity but with diskPath set to "webcache.db".  I've put that in the AppDelegate on didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. I can tell my cache entry has been added by checking the contents of webcache.db and cachedResponseForRequest can find it as well.  I'm wondering, is this working for you?

Comment: I tried adding cache headers. I amended the original post to show how I did that.  Unfortunately that didn't work either